# Bidirectional One-to-many association with foreign key

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

So we have 2 entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "block")
public class Block {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private long id_block;
    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "block",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Subblock> subblock = new ArrayList<>();

    /* getters and setters*/
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "subblock")
public class Subblock {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENT)
    @Column
    private long id_subblock;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_block")
    private Block block;

    @Column
    String name;
    /* getters and setters*/
}
```

As i understand to get id_block in table Subblock i need to link parent-child and child-parent

```
Block block = new Block();
        Subblock subblock = new Subblock();
        List<Subblock>subblockList= new ArrayList();
        subblock.setName("subblock_1"));

        subblock.setBlock(block);/*child-parent*/

        subblockList.add(subblock);
        block.setName("block_1"));
        block.setSubblock(subblockList);/*parent-child*/

        try {
                ratingService.add(block);/*merge the block*/
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

At this case i have right references in table Subblock to field id_block.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(
    private List<Subblock> subblock = new ArrayList<>();
@ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="id_block")
        private Block block;
```

With this case i have simply results without linking child-parent

```
Block block = new Block();
            Subblock subblock = new Subblock();
            List<Subblock>subblockList= new ArrayList();
            subblock.setName("subblock_1"));
            subblockList.add(subblock);
            block.setName("block_1"));
            block.setSubblock(subblockList);/*parent-child*/
            try {
                    ratingService.add(block);
            }
            catch (NullPointerException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

So what is the right way? And is it right to do as the case 2?

Comment: I think in the second scenario after merge the database will be in the same state as in the first one with the cascade all it will update the subblock table. The difference from the first scenario is that subblock will not block property setup until you reload it. The proper way depends on what you want to do

Comment: can it influence on cascade or fetching? As i understand with bidirectional association i can fetching in both direction? For example fetch subblock-block and block-subblock?

Comment: You can but you have already fetched the subblock and hibernate will not update you java object directly. If you add it to the block and merge the block then you update the state in hibernate. The subblock object is already in memory though so you need to refresh it to reflect the changes.  Now if you get the subblock from hibernate it will have its Block updated even though you haven't specifically changed it and saved.

Comment: Were you able to save the block entity in the second case? I think it would fail unless you have join table b/w that stores block id and subblock id in columns.

Comment: The second case works cause the method that inserts the merge object is the same as for the first case. The  Associations are different .